# Can I find length of string of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to find the length of a string of strings. For example;

```
str1 = " 'abc:12s', 'sqw:90', 'df2:90' "   therefore the len(str1) = 3
str2= " 'asq:1v3', 'qws:9' "               therefore the len(str2) = 2
```

Is there a way I can find this frequency and add the frequency to each string inside str1? Need an output like this

```
'abc:12s, 3'
'sqw:90, 3'
'df2:90, 3'
'asq:1v3, 2'
'qws:9, 2'
```

Comment: I’m afraid you’ve forgotten to post your attempt at solving this on your own first.

Comment: A place to start - you could split them into a list with `str1.split(', ')`. Then, you can find the `len` easily and get each individual string easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda function and it will return what you want.

string : str1 = "'abc:12s', 'sqw:90', 'df2:90'"

```
list(map(lambda x: x+str(len(str1.split(","))), str1.split(",")))
```

Result = ["'abc:12s'3", " 'sqw:90'3", " 'df2:90'3"]